# TempData null redirecting to View - after migrating to ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, startup, tempdata

After migrating to `ASP.Net Core 3.0` my `TempData` is always null after redirecting to a View. Is there something wrong or missing at my `startup.cs` code?

Comment: Please don't add code as a comment. Edit your original question and add the code there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this part of code in `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
```

Comment: Thank you! Works fine just with services.AddControllersWithViews().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();